# Modifying R variable assigned to a literal through C leading to strange behavior

Tags: r, rcpp

Does anyone know what is going on with the following R code?

```
library(inline)

increment <- cfunction(c(a = "integer"), "
  INTEGER(a)[0]++;
  return R_NilValue;
")

print_one = function(){
  one = 0L
  increment(one)
  print(one)
}

print_one() # prints 1
print_one() # prints 2
```

The printed results are 1, 2. Replacing `one = 0L` with `one = integer(1)` gives result 1, 1.

Just to clarify. I know I'm passing the variable `one` by reference to the C function, so its value should change (become `1`). What I don't understand is that, how come resetting `one = 0L` seem to have no effect at all after the first call to `print_one` (the second call to `print_one` prints `2` instead of `1`).

Comment: R uses call-by-value semantics with a copy-on-write implementation, and if you write C code that interfaces with R, you're expected to do copy-on-write yourself. You're not allowed to modify function arguments like that.

Comment: I'm just curious what's going on here. How come in the subsequent calls to `print_one`, resetting `one=0L` has no effect (at least that's what seem to be happening)?

Comment: I don't think this question has anything to do with the package Rcpp (or inline). Removed the rcpp tag.

Comment: rcpp is the successor package to inline, written by the same author (Dirk Eddelbuettel). The general recommendation is that you should use rcpp going forward

Answer (score 1):

This really (as the last comment hinted) have little to do with Rcpp. It's really mostly about the `.C()` interface used by the old `inline` package and here by `cfunction` approach in the question.

That leads to two answers.

First, the consensus among R developers is that `.C()` is deprecated and should no longer be used.  Statements to that effect can be found on the r-devel and r-package-devel lists. `.C()` uses plain old types as pointers in the interface so *here* the integer value is passed as `int*` by reference and can be altered.

If we switch to `Rcpp` uses, and hence to the underlying `.Call()` interface using only `SEXP` types for input and output, then an `int` no passes by reference. So the code behaves and prints only `0`:

```
Rcpp::cppFunction("void increment2(int a) { a++; }")

print_two <- function(){
  two <- 0L
  increment2(two)
  print(two)
}

print_two() # prints 0
print_two() # prints 0
```

Lastly, `Rcpp` (capital R) is of course not the "sucessor" to `inline` (as it does a *whole lot more* than `inline` but it among all its functionality is (since around 2013) a quasi-replacement for `inline` in Rcpp Attributes. So with Rcpp 'as-is' since about 2013 you no longer need the examples and approach from `inline`.